# Django AJAX link not entering corresponding view

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

I want users to have the possibility of hiding their posts from the public listing or making it visible once again. My idea was to just have a link that when clicked would change the text and also change the status of a post. Right now the text changes, but the status of the post doesn't, and "I'm here" isn't printed.

This is the view:

```
@login_required
def change_status(request):
    print("I'm here")
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        if request.user.profile.post == post:
            if post.status == 'published':
                post.status = 'hidden'
            else:
                post.status = 'published'
            post.save()
            return HttpResponse("Success!")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Request not from author")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Request method is not a GET")
```

The url:

```
url(r'^status/$', views.change_status, name='change_status'),
```

The template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
<p> {{ post.author }} - {{ post.pub_date }}</p>

{% for tag in post.tags.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'fortykwords:tag' tag.name %}">{{ tag.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}

<p>{{ post.body }}</p>
{% if post.author != request.user %}
<a href="{% url "pinax_messages:message_user_create" user_id=post.author.id %}" class="btn btn-default">Message this user</a>
{% endif %}
{% if post.author == request.user %}
    {% if post.status == 'published' %}
    <a class="likebutton" id="like{{post.id}}" href="#" data-catid="{{ post.id }}">Hide post</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if post.status == 'hidden' %}
    <a class="likebutton" id="like{{post.id}}" href="#" data-catid="{{ post.id }}">Make post public again</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.likebutton').click(function(){
    var catid;
    catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"GET",
        url: "/status",
        data:{
                 post_id: catid
        },
        success: function( data ) 
        {
            $( '#like'+ catid ).text("changed");
            $( '#message' ).text(data);
        }
     })
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

And the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('hidden', 'Hidden'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
        ('banned', 'Banned'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    body = models.TextField(max_length=40000)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='hidden')
    author = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    tags = tagulous.models.TagField(force_lowercase=True, max_count=15,autocomplete_view='fortykwords:post_tags_autocomplete')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The text changes as according to `$( '#like'+ catid ).text("changed");` so jquery loaded right, but since it doesn't print "I'm here" I am assuming that it doesn't enter the view. The GET request does happen, though: `[21/Aug/2018 16:46:59] "GET /status?post_id=10 HTTP/1.1" 302 0`. Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just use a flag in your model? `hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)` and then you can add a radio button in your template and if you'd like you can use ajax to modify it's state.

Comment: Is there any important difference between using a choice variable and a boolean? Could I use your radio button with this view?

Comment: In this case the flag would be cleaner. you can use radio buttons in either case.

Comment: What should I have in the url instead?

Comment: Is the status changing for the post? Are you receiving any http response data? Are you logged in?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 302, this means your request is being redirected, I suspect to the login page because of @login_required.

Comment: The status is not changing. I don't know if I'm receiving... It does execute the code inside  success: function( data ) . The user is logged in, and can successfully execute other views and templates that require login. Removing the login_required does not fix anything. In my urls I have     url(r'^.*$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='fortykwords:index', permanent=False)), which redirects to the index anytime the user goes to an illegal url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I changed it to a POST request instead of a GET request, since we are changing the data after all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.likebutton').click(function(){
    var catid;
    catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url: "/status/",
        data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
                post_id: catid
        },
        success: function( data ) 
        {
            $( '#like'+ catid ).text("changed");
            $( '#message' ).text(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Please report this error: "+errorThrown+xhr.status+xhr.responseText);
        }
     })
});
```

(I added `{% csrf_token %}` to the view, of course).

and the view ended up being:

```
@login_required
def change_status(request):
    print("I'm here")
    if request.is_ajax():
        post_id = request.POST['post_id']
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        if request.user.profile.post == post:
            if post.status == 'published':
                post.status = 'hidden'
            else:
                post.status = 'published'
            post.save()
            return HttpResponse("Success!")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Request not from author")
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Now it works just fine.

Comment: Note that it's not good practice to send the CSRF token in the request body. It should be added in the request's header (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request)